# ExtJs How do I scroll to the bottom of a grid?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs

I am making a web-based logviewer using extjs.

I would like new log-lines to be added to the bottom of my gridview as it saves cpu by not requiring a sort to move it to the top of the grid (plus its how my coworkers prefer it).

My problem is that ideally the grid would scroll to the bottom after a new row is added.

I have been looking through the documentation and I cannot figure out how to do this.  I just see a method to scroll to the top.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use GridView's `focusRow` method, e.g.:

```
myGrid.getView().focusRow(20);
```

If you don't already have the row index you'll have to retrieve it using one of GridView's related methods for finding a row.